# is it possible to embed a linux terminal in another linux terminal in text mode

Tags: bash, tty

i seen this before in a utility called Yast on a opensuse

what i need is to create a bash script that displays some text
and run command2

(for example: cd php-src; ./configure ;make; make install )

i want the output of command2 to be displayed as it runs in a region of
the main bash script

in graphic mode, QT library support embeding a terminal

i am looking for such a solution for text mode

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, GNU Screen can do tiling:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/GNU-Screen-Tutorial-44274.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Yast isn't just a shell script. It uses [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) for drawing stuff in the terminal.
Tiling your terminal with only bash is hard I think.